# Webservice - loading properties file

Tags: java, web-services, properties, loading

I'm creating a webservice which connects to server A, sends a message M and gets a response message R back. The values to connect to server A are in a properties file which I need to load in the webservice. Since I connect to the same server everytime, (i just send diff messages and get appropriate response back) I just want to load the properties file just once. I don't want to load the properties file everytime the webservice gets called so I can improve the performance. Can you please tell me how I would be able to achieve this? I'm planning to deploy this webservice on to a tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to load your properties

Answer (score 0):

Standard java property file should do just fine , create

```
   static public Properties prop;
```

initialize it and just use it throughout your app

Comment: Wow that was simple. Thanks a lot. Will def try and let you know the result.

Comment: and what is the result :?, if all is good check answer as good :)